# Add links to PDF programmatically

Tags: pdf, itext

I have about 180 PDF files that are generated from a geodatabase.  I would like to programmatically add links as hot spots (no text) at the top, bottom, left and right as needed to navigate to the adjoining page files.  I would also like to add links over a 3x3 grid in the lower left corner of the page for additional navigation.  The grid is already in the existing PDF just no links.  Total there will be a possible 14 links added to each page

I am open to suggestions as to how to go about this.  I am using Acrobat Pro XI, and I am familiar with various programing languages python, vb.net, C#...  Just no experience working directly with PDF files.

Comment: Implementing that should be possible with any general-purpose PDF library. Is it not possible to make the scenario more concrete? E.g. you said nothing about licensing conditions and available budget.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  There will be only one person in need of a license if required.  The end product will be used internally only.  I did find a product that supports adding links at specific locations called Debenu for about $450.  It would be worth that cost in the time savings for the initial run alone but it is a little excessive in I would only be using 1 of over 900 functions.  Was initially looking for a solution using adobe SDK or something along the lines of a open source python module. If even possible/available.  Just need some direction as to what is available.

Comment: ;) that doesn't really restrict the choices too much. @Bobrovski pointed towards Docotic. I'm personally more knowledgeable concerning iText (Sharp) and would point there. But i actually cannot vote *against* any general purpose library based on the current information.

Comment: I have ran across iTextSharp but could not find any code references to placing links (border less link areas to another pdf file) at specific locations in a pdf files.  Can you provide a reference or example. Also could you please add an answer rather than a comment.  May be a possible solution that I would like to be able to select an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After continuing to search and not finding any other promising open source solutions I went with [Debenu Quick PDF Library](http://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-library/).  The specific functions I used are are noted below:

- [AddLinkToFile](http://www.debenu.com/docs/pdf_library_reference/AddLinkToFile.php)
- [AddLinkToPage](http://www.debenu.com/docs/pdf_library_reference/AddLinkToPage.php)
- [Other annotations and hotspot links](http://www.debenu.com/docs/pdf_library_reference/AnnotationsAndHotspotLinks.php)

The time that the two library functions are going to save me weekly is worth the cost alone.  I am sure I will find other use for the other 900+ PDF functions

Answer (score 3):

This is very late answer. Actually I was searching for free alternative to above paid libraries. I found the following links which can be helpful to others.

[Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) is a vast java library to create pdf programmatically.

[TomRoush/PdfBox-Android](https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android) is it's android implementation. You can find the sample project with this implementation.

I have added the code for creating clickable links in pdf by using above android library and sample project.

```
public void createPdf(View v) {
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    document.addPage(page);

    // Create a new font object selecting one of the PDF base fonts
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    // Or a custom font
    //try {
    //  PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(document, assetManager.open("MyFontFile.TTF"));
    //} catch(IOException e) {
    //  e.printStackTrace();
    //}

    PDPageContentStream contentStream;

    try {
        // Define a content stream for adding to the PDF
        contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

        String preText = "Icons made by ";
        String linkText = "My_Site";

        float upperRightX = page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightX();
        float upperRightY = page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightY();
        // Write linkText in blue text
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(15, 38, 192);
        contentStream.setFont(font, 18);
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( 0, upperRightY-20);
        contentStream.drawString(preText + linkText);
        contentStream.endText();

        // create a link annotation
        PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();

        // set up the markup area
        float offset = (font.getStringWidth(preText) / 1000) * 18;
        float textWidth = (font.getStringWidth(linkText) / 1000) * 18;
        PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
        position.setLowerLeftX(offset);
        position.setLowerLeftY(upperRightY - 24f);
        position.setUpperRightX(offset + textWidth);
        position.setUpperRightY(upperRightY -4);
        txtLink.setRectangle(position);

        // add an action
        PDActionURI action = new PDActionURI();
        action.setURI("https://www.**********.com/");
        txtLink.setAction(action);

        // and that's all ;-)
        page.getAnnotations().add(txtLink);

        // load 'Social media' icons from 'vector' resources.
        float padding = 5, startX = 5, startY = upperRightY-100, width = 25, height=25;
        loadVectorIconWithLink(document, page, contentStream, R.drawable.ic_facebook,
                "https://www.facebook.com/My_Name/", startX, startY, width, height);
        startX += (width + padding);
        loadVectorIconWithLink(document, page, contentStream, R.drawable.ic_instagram,
                "https://www.instagram.com/My_Name", startX, startY, width, height);

        // Make sure that the content stream is closed:
        contentStream.close();

        // Save the final pdf document to a file
        String path = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/Created.pdf";
        document.save(path);
        document.close();
        tv.setText("Successfully wrote PDF to " + path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void loadVectorIconWithLink( PDDocument theDocument,
                                     PDPage thePage,
                                     PDPageContentStream theContentStream,
                                     @DrawableRes int theDrawableId,
                                     String theUriString,
                                     float x, float y, float width, float height
                                     ) throws IOException
{
    Bitmap alphaImage = getBitmapFromDrawable(this, theDrawableId);
    PDImageXObject alphaXimage = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(theDocument, alphaImage);
    theContentStream.drawImage(alphaXimage, x, y, width, height );

    // create a link annotation
    PDAnnotationLink iconLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
    PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle( x, y, width, height );
    iconLink.setRectangle(position);

    // add an action
    PDActionURI action1 = new PDActionURI();
    action1.setURI(theUriString);
    iconLink.setAction(action1);

    // and that's all ;-)
    thePage.getAnnotations().add(iconLink);
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Context context, @DrawableRes int drawableId) {
    Drawable drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawableId);

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    } else if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawableCompat || drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unsupported drawable type");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this solution help add links to an existing PDF-file? Or is it create-only. The thing is there a ton of create-only libraries for PDF. And very few that enable to edit pre-existing PDFs.

Comment: @Gherman I think this code is only for creating new pdf document.

Comment: You can modify a PDF file to add a link, use load instead of create a new PDDocument:
 
     val document = PDDocument.load(filePath)
     val page = document.getPage(0)

Comment: I have to use the com.tom_roush:pdfbox-android:1.8.10.3 with this version because the newer version didn't work for me.

Comment: @jachumbelechao, thanks for your comment. This will help all users.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three types of links you might want to add: links to pages within the same document, links to pages in other PDF document, links to URLs on the web.

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can add links of any of these types (please note that I am on of the developers of this library). Here are two relevant examples:

- [Create link to page](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Pages%20and%20Navigation/LinkToPage)
- [Create hyperlink](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Pages%20and%20Navigation/Hyperlink)

There are no examples for how to create links to pages in an other PDF document published online, but you can always contact support if you need such an example.