# How do I add a hyperlink to a PdfDocument page canvas?

Tags: java, android, canvas, hyperlink, href

Good day. I'm building a simple pdf report using native PrintedPdfDocument class and I need to insert a text with hyperlink into a document. This is my simple implementation of pdf page.

```
PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(context, attributes);
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, 1).create();
PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
Canvas c = page.getCanvas();
TextPaint p = new TextPaint();
```

Here a several ways I had tried but still no luck.

First way using a Canvas drawText() method. Result: "some link" without hyperlink.

```
c.drawText("<a href='https://example.com'>some link</a>", 30, 30, p);
```

Second way using SpannableString. Result: "some link".

```
String link = "https://example.com";  
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("some link");
s.setSpan(new URLSpan(link), 0, link.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
c.drawText(s.toString(), 30, 30, p);
```

Third way using StaticLayout. Result: blank space.

```
Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml("<a href='https://example.com'>some link</a>", null, null);
StaticLayout l = new StaticLayout(spanned, p, 30, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
l.draw(c);
```

TextView do not draw anything to Canvas.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100));
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href='https://example.com'>some link</a>"));
tv.draw(c);
```

Maybe you better know how to deal with it?

Comment: Have you found any breakthrough to this issue ? Please let us know ..

Comment: Still no solution.

Comment: I had to use Apache PdfBox library and it's android project TomRouch/PdfBox-Android to add links to pdf in android project. You may see the answer link https://stackoverflow.com/a/54400313/2641380

Comment: Thank you. Anyway still searching for the native solution.