# How to render pdf with clickable links?

Tags: android, pdf

I use PdfRenderer class to render pdf. However, the problem is that in this approach I can't make the hyperlinks in the document clickable.

Is there any better way to render pdf in android application?

I am aware of using webview with google docs, but I want the app to work offline so this solution is not suitable.

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10352422/10592895.

Answer (score -2):

Try using pdfjs that is used by Mozilla.

Follow this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26086480/10587375

> This method works for sure on Android 4.0 and above

Comment: this does not show pdf with links. but just renders pdf, which i anyways can do with pdfRendered

Comment: I was searching for this for some time, then I used library for this. You may check answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54400313/2641380